# Error en Carrito de Compras en Symfony

Tags: symfony

Estoy trabajando en crear un carrito de compras para un proyecto que estoy realizando  y estoy utilizando Symfony6, al momento de entrar al url del carrito para probar su funcionamiento  me da este error, he buscado en internet y probado algunas de las soluciones pero no me han servido.

> Cannot autowire argument $cartManager of
> "App\Controller\Frontend\CartController::index()": it references class
> "App\Manager\CartManager" but no such service exists.

Este es el código del controlador del Carrito:

```
namespace App\Controller\Frontend;

use App\Form\CartType;
use App\Manager\CartManager;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

/**
 * Class CartController
 * @package App\Controller
 */
class CartController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/cart", name="cart")
     */
    public function index(CartManager $cartManager, Request $request): Response
    {
        $cart = $cartManager->getCurrentCart();

        $form = $this->createForm(CartType::class, $cart);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $cart->setUpdateAt(new \DateTime());
            $cartManager->save($cart);

            return $this->redirectToRoute('cart');
        }

        return $this->render('cart/index.html.twig', [
            'cart' => $cart,
            'form' => $form->createView()
        ]);
    }
}
```

Este es el código del Manager del Carrito

```
namespace App\Manager;

use App\Entity\Order;
use App\Factory\OrderFactory;
use App\Storage\CartSessionStorage;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;

class CartManager
{
    /**
     * @var CartSessionStorage
     */
    private $cartSessionStorage;

    /**
     * @var OrderFactory
     */
    private $cartFactory;

    /**
     * @var EntityManagerInterface
     */
    private $entityManager;

    /**
     * CartManager constructor.
     */
    public function __construct(
        CartSessionStorage $cartStorage,
        OrderFactory $orderFactory,
        EntityManagerInterface $entityManager
    ) {
        $this->cartSessionStorage = $cartStorage;
        $this->cartFactory = $orderFactory;
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the current cart.
     */
    public function getCurrentCart(): Order
    {
        $cart = $this->cartSessionStorage->getCart();

        if (!$cart) {
            $cart = $this->cartFactory->create();
        }

        return $cart;
    }

    /**
     * Persists the cart in database and session.
     */
    public function save(Order $cart): void
    {
        // Persist in database
        $this->entityManager->persist($cart);
        $this->entityManager->flush();
        // Persist in session
        $this->cartSessionStorage->setCart($cart);
    }
}
```

No se que me esta faltando la verdad, he revisado pero no logro entender el porque del error. agradecería su ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Buenas Noches ya vi el problema donde estaba.

La Clase CartManager tiene como namespace App\Manager, y dicho fichero estaba ubicado en otro lugar App\Manger, me falto poner la a al momento de crear la carpeta, al fin logre que funcionara.